# Cannot find a module angular 4

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular-module

Initially the app displays login page and navigates to maincontent component now i want to navigate from dashboard component to app details component but am getting an error as

`Error: Component DashboardComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.`

In my app.module.ts i have imported all the components

below is the routes that i have mentioned in app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes=[
    { path:'', redirectTo:'/login',pathMatch:'full'},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'maincontent', loadChildren: 
'./maincontent/maincontent.module#MainContentModule'
    }
];
```

below is the routes mentioned in MainContentModule

```
 export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'maincontent',
    component: MainContentComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component:DashboardComponent,
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
        ]
      }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports:[
    RouterModule,
  ]
})
export class MainContentModule {}
```

In my DasboardModule

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path:'dashboard', component:DashboardComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path:'application',component:ApplicationDetailsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)
  ],
  declarations: [   ],
  exports:[
    RouterModule,
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `DashboardComponent` in your `MainContentModule` declarations:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)
  ],
  declarations: [DashboardComponent ],
  exports:[
    RouterModule,
  ]
})
```

Comment: Error: Type DashboardComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: MainContentModule and AppModule! Please consider moving DashboardComponent to a higher module that imports MainContentModule and AppModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes DashboardComponent then import that NgModule in MainContentModule and AppModule.

Comment: is `MainContentModule` imported in your `AppModule` ?

Comment: Yes i have imported in Appmodule

Comment: then remove the `DashboardComponent` from `AppModule` declarations and just keep it in the `MainContentModule` declarations as @Sajeetharan mentioned.

Comment: I have removed from AppModule but now it gives me another error

Comment: Template parse errors:
'md-option' is not a known element:

Comment: do you have `MaterialModule` imported in your `AppModule`? If not then do so ~

Comment: I have imported Material Module in AppModule @Faisal

Comment: Your current problem stated in the question is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted, and post the other error as a new question with error details and some code.

Comment: Okay Thank you for your time